# Is there a term for the combination of principal and credential?

Tags: terminology

In an API that needs to take a principal and a credential as arguments, what is the pair of those two pieces of information commonly called?

FFW Apache Shiro seems to call this an AuthenticationToken. Is that established terminology though?

Answer (score 1):

One common term for this is "[Credential Pair](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22credential%20pair%22)", which references the combination of identification token and authentication token, while recognizing that the bare word "credential" is often used to reference the authentication token.

Another term, used less commonly and with less precision, is the plural "Credentials", again referencing the combination of multiple elements.